# What does sonarqube C++ code scans in preview mode do?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I just ran a sonar-scanner in preview mode,  I cannot find any files generated by the execution.  the output of the run is equally not useful.

```
....
INFO: 3645 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3650 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3653 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3657 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3659 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3662 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3664 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3665 compilation units analyzed, current is file.cpp
INFO: 3666 compilation units analyzed
INFO: PPH: 6803 files, 71566094 bytes, 2359139 hits, 2365942 queries
INFO: Sensor CPP (done) | time=10649441ms
INFO: Performing issue tracking
INFO: 8778/8778 components tracked
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:57:37.875s
INFO: Final Memory: 91M/6230M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not actually supposed to be terribly useful. It's there for technical uses. Instead, you should investigate [SonarLint](http://sonarlint.org), which offers both IDE integration and a command-line version for pre-commit analysis.

Through a combination of [SonarC++ 4.4.0](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/2017/01/2017-01-05-sonarqube-c-cpp-objectivec-4.4.0-6266-released.html) and SonarLint for Eclipse CDT, you also get C/C++ support.

Comment: Actually, sonarlint CLI cannot load property files.  Our sonar-project.properties files are complex and layered.  Having to maintain json files beside them is probably a dealbreaker for us.

Comment: last reply was actually applied to our java projects sorry.

Does SonarLint need the json file created by the c++ build wrapper? 

A new question also,   With dramatically different configuration sonarlint guarantee to find the same issues as the server scanner?  one of the big issues we have with sonarqube 4.5 is incremental scans do not find all the issues a full/publish scan does.  this causes frustration with our developers.

Comment: With "dramatically different" configuration? No. You should contact support with the more in depth questions. You'll bet better follow-thru than on SO. :-)